# C#: Running a process on button click

Tags: c#, wpf

I am running a process on button click of my WPF application as shown below:

```
private void btnGetValues_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string arg1 = "1";
    Process p1 = new Process();
    p1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    p1.StartInfo.FileName = "myexe.exe";
    p1.StartInfo.Arguments = arg1;
    p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p1.Start();

    //while (!p1.HasExited)
    //{

    //}

    MessageBox.Show(p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
}
```

The problem is that even after the process executes, the button continues to remain in clicked state. What could be the problem?

Comment: Is it really in clicked state, or only with focus? I've noticed that buttons with focus on a simple WPF app seem to be clicked (their color changes in a fading way). Try just sending the focus to the button (tabbing to it) instead of clicking it to see if this is the same behavior you're seeing.

Comment: Oh, just realized it is just in focus. What should I do about it?

Comment: what type button you use? vs-control or other control?

Comment: Is it a problem that the button is in focus?

Comment: do you you use any style or template? even you can also `capture image from different state` and post here as **edit**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need the last message box? get read of it and it should work. If you are still experiencing problems then you can run it in a separate thread. That is a way of executing multiple things at the same time. [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is an example.

Edit

sorry I understood the wrong thing. You can set the focus to something else if you wish the button to lose that appearance.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string arg1 = "1";
            Process p1 = new Process();
            p1.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            p1.StartInfo.FileName = @"yourExecutable";
            p1.StartInfo.Arguments = arg1;
            p1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p1.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            p1.Start();
            //while (!p1.HasExited)
            //{

            // }

            MessageBox.Show(p1.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

            button2.Focus();  // set button 2 to have a height of 0 so it is not visible
            // or place it somewhere where it cannot be seen



        }
```